TxTextControl - How to prevent adding a new line at the end of an RTF document?
I use TxTextControl v22 to process RTF files.
My RTF file should end with a dot character as a standard ending of a sentence.
Every time I use the Save method, after re-reading the file content I notice that at the end of the document a new extra blank line (ENTER) is added right after the dot that should end the document content.
How to prevent adding a new line at the end of an RTF document?
